# Gem CanCanCan e Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancancan

I use the gems `devise`, `cancancan`, and `rails_admin` in my project. I added:

```
before_action: authenticate_user!
```

in the `application_controller` as recommended by `devise`.

It works as long as the the administrative part of the site is concerned. The root page of the site should not need authentication, but it actually requires login to enter. I imagine this is because of putting the callback in `application_controller.rb`.

I would like to know how to restrict and require login only on some pages of the site, but not on pages in which the users should access without the need of a login, such as the root page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ApplicationController` is an ancestor of all controllers. If you put a callback in this controller, then that would be called from any controller on your app. To execute the callback only from certain controllers, move the callback:

```
before_action: authenticate_user!
```

from `ApplicationController`, and place it in the class body of the controllers that should require authentication.

Comment: Wow, I have not thought of that before. 
I'll test. Thanks for the help and sorry for my bad English! (Google 
translator)